# What's wrong with this jquery POST

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to make a script to post to my codeigniter controller, this is what I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input.atualizar').click(function(){
      var observacoes = $('textarea#textarea_observacoes').val();
      var pac_id = $('input#member_id').val();
      var tipo = 'observacoes';

        $.post("pacientes/update", { "observacoes" : observacoes, "pac_id" : pac_id, "tipo" : tipo },
        function(data){
            alert(data.result);
            alert('aaaa');
        }, "json");
   }); 

});
```

yet It's not doing anything, not alerting anything from alert(data.result), not posting, nothing on the debugger, this is my php function

```
    function update(){
        $ar = array(
            'observacoes' => $this->input->post('observacoes'),
            'pac_id' => $this->input->post('pac_id'),
            'tipo' => $this->input->post('tipo')
        );
        echo json_encode($ar);
    }
```

Comment: You need an extra `});` on your code. The version you posted will cause a syntax error, and may be the cause for nothing happening.

Comment: Is your file really called update, without extension?

Comment: @bfavaretto I'm curious as to where? I've been scanning this code and there doesn't seem to be any }) missing

Comment: It's a codeigniter controller, that's why it's without extension

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin, I'm sorry, you're right, I was confused by the way the code is formatted

Comment: @AndréAbadesso, what happens when you access the same URL directly from the browser, without posting anything? Greetings from Brazil!

Comment: Greetings @bfavaretto, when I access the URL (pacientes/update) without posting anything I get the empty json response:
{"observacoes":false,"pac_id":false,"tipo":false}

Comment: @AndréAbadesso, it *might* be that you are getting a silent error when trying to access `data.result`, which does not exist (there's no `result` property on your JSON object).

Comment: I just tried to alert data.observacao and data.pac_id and it didn't work, this is so weird

Comment: Are you using Firebug? Do you see any errors on the console? Do you see the ajax request being fired (on the console)?

Comment: I was using google chrome's console, just tried firebug, It's posting correctly but getting "pai/index.php/pacientes/" html, (current is pai/index.php/pacientes/form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to see the exception:

```
    <div class="fail" style="display: none;z-index:999">
        <div>
            Error....
            <div id="errorTextMsg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
<script>
   $(".fail").ajaxError(function (event, xhr, status, error) {
                $("#errorTextMsg").html(xhr.responseText);
                $(this).show();
            })

});
</script>
```

Comment: It outputted "Error...." and inside the div it showed the previous part of the website lol

Comment: Hey! This explains everything! I think Codeigniter is outputting a layout along with what you are echoing. That's not valid JSON as your callback would be expecting.

Comment: Yea, I just figured that out when you asked me to use firebug and I saw the ../ url's html being output, i'm loading the view from the search form instead of redirecting to a new controller or function! thanks for your help, I believe I fixed it !!

Answer (score 1):

Is the 'aaaa' alerting?

`data.result` doesn't look like it is set in your JSON. Try to alert `data.observacoes` instead.

Comment: aaaa is not alerting and I just tried data.observacoes and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I think this is spanish, not sure, but if this is the case, did you mistype:

```
input.atualizar
```

Cause i'm pretty sure it should be

```
input.actualizar
```

No?

Comment: It's Portuguese, looks like Brazilian Portuguese (in Portugal they'd use that extra 'c' as in Spanish)

Comment: If your answer is not correct (may be he didn't mistype) but I like your answer. How do you know Spanish ?

Comment: I don't speak spanish, the word "Atualizar" looked like "update" in my mind, i went to google translate after posting just to confirm and yes, it should be "Actualizar" if you want it to match to "Update" in english

Comment: In Brazilian portuguese it's atualizar

Comment: "Atualizar" means "update" indeed. But it's correctly spelled in Brazilian Portuguese. Google may be wrong, or it thinks it's Spanish.